# amcl laser localization

Tags: localization, navigation, laser, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have a question.

I have created a map using slam_gmapping package, then I save that map as map.yaml using  rosrun map_server map_saver -f map.

Is it possible to use a laser and  the map I have created with amcl for localization?

I appreciate your answer :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60552/amcl-laser-localization/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: Yes, it is possible. Use the map_server to publish your saved map, start amcl and use rviz to estimate the inital pose. Then move your robot around and see, if the localization is working. :)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-04-12**:
well, I do the following: I use rosrun map_server map_server map.yaml then in another console I use rosrun amcl amcl scan. Then the only topic I see in rviz under  Pose is /move_base_simple/goal.  I supposed to see amcl_pose topic under Pose, right?

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-04-12**:
According to the docs, amcl publishes the pose as `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped`. But you can also add displays for the particlecloud (`geometry_msgs/PoseArray`) and tf. Through tf, amcl should publish the most likely transform between your map and odom.

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-04-12**:
well, i have 2 issues, 1.-how i can set the initial pose 2--why my map gets rotated after I have published it and visualized in rviz?

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-04-12**:\

1. In rviz you should have a "2d pose estimate" button. 2) Depending on your fixed frame, the visualized map can rotate if the best guess by amcl changes. Try setting the fixed frame to /map in rviz.

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-04-14**:
Well, it seems to be as it everything is working, the only issue now is how to see the estimated poses produced by amcl in rviz? in other words, how can I see that amcl is working?

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-04-14**:
Add a display of type `PoseArray` to rviz, set the topic to /particlecloud and then drive around a little bit. You then should see all the pose-guesses of amcl as small arrows in rviz.

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-04-15**:
Well, it seems to be as PoseAarray is working under rviz, however, from the beginning the amcl algorithm spreads particles even outside the map. Is that normal? or is there a way to fix it?

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-04-15**:
Since amcl publishes the pose as geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped, how can I see the poses with covariance under rviz?

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-04-15**:
Thats normal. You can use the "2d pose estimate" in rviz to give it a hint, where to start. (Click the button and drag the arrow on the map.) Regarding the visualization of PoseWithCovarianceStamped: I dont know if that is possible. (rviz does not seem to have a builtin display for that...)

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-04-18**:
Well, it seems to be as if the navigation is working properly. Just one issue 1.-when I set the '2d pose estimate' and then '2d nav goal' the robot goes to the goal with a lot of rotations, is there any way to make the robot goes a straight line?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-11-21**:
I guess visualizing PoseWithCovarianceStamped is not available in rviz currently but you can 'rostopic echo amcl_pose' to see the message that feedback to you every time the filter update.